# How to recover from bad VBox Guest Additions build?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, repair, guest-additions

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (fully patched). Last week, the kernel took an update. So I [virtually] inserted the VBox Guest Additions CD and then proceeded to build it. I don't recall having any problems.

I've been trying to start the machine all week. I'm now in at a place where I get through GRUB and begin to boot, but the machine just hangs. The error is *"attempt to read or write outside of disk `hd0'"*.

[image]

I've run [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) on the machine and it reports everything is OK. I've even allowed it to make changes, which results in the same problem. The Boot Repair dump of system information can be found on [Ubuntu Pastebin, Item 10867601](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10867601/).

Googling returns [spurious noise](https://www.google.com/#q=recover+from+bad+vbox+guest+additions+build) when searching for "VBox Guest Additions Recover".

How do I recover from a bad VBox Guest Additions build?